# Typescript - auto inherit props type in React callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Having this implementation

```
// CustomComponent.ts
type SaveProps = {
    date: string;
    name: string;
}

interface IProps {
    onSave: (props: SaveProps) => void;
}

const CustomComponent = ({onSave}: IProps) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => onSave({ date: '', name: '' })}>
            Click me
        </button>
    );
};


// ParentComponent.ts
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent';

export default function ParentComponent () {
    
    const saveData = props => { // what type is props? how to infer this as SaveProps defined in CustomComponent.ts?
        
    }

    return (
        <CustomComponent onSave={saveData} />
    )
}
```

How can I infer the type of props in **saveData** as being **Props** without having to import the type? So that when reading the props in saveData callback, I would automatically know what kind of data CustomComponent is sending back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, it is better to export `Props` type along with the component. In your particular case you can do the following:

```
import { IProps, CustomComponent } from './CustomComponent';

function ParentComponent () {
    const saveData = React.useCallback((props => {
    }) as IProps['onSave'], []);

    return (
        <CustomComponent onSave={saveData} />
    )
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCoHoa4BhAVwGcZcHdIA7JbmAHQwWVGAE8wSOAGUUANyQAFHGBZwAvHADeVOHrgATFDCQAuOGyjBuAcwqV9cbihBmLMK7fsBfKlWsmUJjoUgCSyhCq2rr6ENyyCuYAFGAqLOYJSmkAlBoAfHByEMAGPn6UmEzcGMBxjKzsIJzgcXwwSVpxmd7m4TnRDvpEMExQ3HBJMY56ADwARkww7ONxDAA2wGgA1upaSbnqBV3ySB2Gxm74%20AA0Ti6X%20HDe2d55U9OO65tbcK7vjjMaAslnE3oM9NkfPYqJVqjBauNFCgiPxmjw2hNcjpwXA0HE2BYTgARYwoDSIYiCVhIBgoNZrOboLZJFJpfIDRzPOAoNR9SIsADa%20GOCnwAF1bgKxZDyo5hqNxpMcQDmGwOFxWvw4CKkLsWMTSd44DQwY5slRvEA)

Comment: yes, importing does makes the deal, but isn't there any other elegant solution? :)

Comment: I'll stick with this one

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for one more answer. Comments are restricted by max length.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing

TS is smart enough to infer types in different directions, And its managed by a bunch of heuristic algorithms. That's why we can not refactor your example according to some generic ruleset (there is no such).

One more trick without explicit export of `Props`:

```
(props => {
}) as Parameters<typeof CustomComponent>[0]['onSave']
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCoHoa4BhAVwGcZcHdIA7JbmAHQwWVGAE8wSOAGUUANyQAFHGBZwAvHADeVOHrgATFDCQAuOGyjBuAcwqV9cbihBmLMK7fsBfKlWsmUJjoUgCSyhCq2rr6ENyyCuYAFGAqLOYJSmkAlBoAfHByEMAGPn6USAAekLBwmEzcGMBxjKzsIJzgcXwwSVpxmd7m4TnRDvpEMExQ3HBJMY56ADwARkww7LNxDAA2wGgA1upaSbnqBQPySH2Gxm74%20AA0Ti73%20HDe2d55C4uOu-sDnBXL9HEsaGsNnEfuM9NkfPYqFUalgGk0WooUER%20J0eD05rkdLC4Gg4mwLFcACLGFAaRDEQSsJAMFA7HYrdAHJIpNL5MaOT5wFBqTFQV6BFhLcSSCCYVpsDhcbr8PIAbQADABdVX4S4KfCa56qzXw8qOSbTWbzYlg5gKjpK3j8OB6pDHFhUmneOA0GGObJUbxAA)

Comment: hmm, yes, that's also a way to go, but much more cumbersome that the "import one"...